# statsmodelformula.api.ols.fit().pvalues returns a Pandas series instead of numpy array

Tags: pandas, statsmodels

So this may be hard to explain cause its a chunk of some really large code - I don't expect it to be reproducible.

But essentially it's a simulation which (using multiple simulated datasets) creates a one-way or two-way regression and calculates the respective t-values and p-values for them.

However, putting some of the datasets (with the same information and no missing values), **results in stats.model.formula.ols.fit() returning the pvals / tvals as a pandas series instead of a numpy array (even one way studies)**.

Could someone please explain why / if there is a way to specify the output?

An example dataframe looks like this: (x0-x187 is our y, genotype and treatment are the desired factors, staging is a factor used for normalisation)

|  | x0 | x1 | ... | treatment | genotype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200926_ku20_e1_wt_veh | 0.075821 | 0.012796 | ... | veh | wt |
| 201210_ku25_e7_wt_veh | 0.082307 | 0.007596 | ... | veh | wt |
| 201127_ku55_e6_wt_veh | 0.083049 | 0.008978 | ... | veh | wt |
| 201220_ku52_e2_wt_veh | 0.078414 | 0.013488 | ... | veh | wt |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 210913_b6ku_22297_e5_wt | 0.067858 | 0.008081 | ... | treat | wt |
| 210821_b6ku_3_e5_wt | 0.070417 | 0.012396 | ... | treat | wt |

And then the code:
'''import subprocess as sub
import os
import struct
from pathlib import Path
import tempfile
from typing import Tuple
import shutil

```
from logzero import logger as logging

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf


for col in range(data.shape[1]):

    if not df[f'x{col}'].any():
        p = np.nan
        t = np.nan
    else:
        if two_way:
            # two way model - if its just the geno or treat comparison; the one-factor col 
            # will
            # be ignored
            # for some simulations smf is returning a Series.

            fit = smf.ols(formula=f'x{col} ~ genotype * treatment + staging', data=df, missing='drop').fit()

            # get all pvals except intercept and staging

            p = fit.pvalues[~fit.pvalues.index.isin(['Intercept', 'staging'])]
            t = fit.tvalues[~fit.tvalues.index.isin(['Intercept', 'staging'])]
        else:
            fit = smf.ols(formula=f'x{col} ~ genotype + staging', data=df, missing='drop').fit()
            p = fit.pvalues['genotype[T.wt]']
            t = fit.tvalues['genotype[T.wt]']
    pvals.append(p)
    tvals.append(t)


p_all = np.array(pvals)
print("example", p_all[0])
print(type(p_all[0][0]), p_all[0][0])
```

And finally some output:

Desired output:
'''example [1.63688492e-01 6.05907115e-06 7.70710934e-02]
<class 'numpy.float64'> 0.16368849176977607 '''

"Error" output:

```
'''example genotype[T.wt]                     0.862423
treatment[T.veh]                   0.000177
genotype[T.wt]:treatment[T.veh]    0.522066
dtype: float64
< class 'numpy.float64'> 0.8624226150886212'''
```

I've manually corrected the data but I would rather not have to do dumb fixes  in the future.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is? parameters, pvalues, tvalues in multiple regression are vectors. statsmodels either returns a numpy array or a pandas series depending on what was used for the provided data. It will never return a scalar value.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was meant to say numpy array instead of float (edited).
What I'm basically asking is what data will cause statsmodels to return a pandas series vs a numpy array?

Comment: Something in my data is proccing statsmodels to return a series and I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: pandas in - pandas out. You use pandas in your data, so the wrapped output uses also pandas.  You can get access to the underlying results instance that does not have the pandas wrapper with `fit._results`. params, pvalues, ... will then be numpy arrays.